# I have 2 input text. I want to disable one input text when the user try to the something to another input text. Im using HTML CSS PHP Thanks

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Part Number:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="text" name="partnum" value="<?php echo $partnum; ?>" style="width: 400px;" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Serial Number:</label>
<input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="text" name="serialnum" value="<?php echo $serialnum; ?>" style="width: 400px;" required>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to use javascript for this. Also please format your question properly, it is not possible to help you without seeing what you have tried so far.

Comment: okay sir thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("tobedisabled").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange = "myFunction()" />
<input type="text" id="tobedisabled" />
```